# Hybris Backoffice Data Hub Build Failed

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Im trying to install Backoffice Data Hub into my existing Hybris 6.2. I followed the steps described in hybris help An error described in the the attached pic during the `build :ant clean all` 
here is also in attached the updated

BUILD ERROR:
[image: BUILD ERROR]

localextensionss.xml:
[image: localextensionss.xml]

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by the fact that your file is named "localextensionss.xml"(there is one extra "s" at the end) instead of "localextensions.xml".